# Setting MessageHeaders.To field gets overwritten

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-client

Here's the scenario: I'm trying to send a SOAP message to an intermediary router service. That service only cares about my SOAP message headers, and uses the [WS-Addressing](http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/#_Toc77464323) `To` header to forward along my message.

I need to basically POST a request like the following to the router service:

```
POST http://gatewayRouter/routingService HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: gatewayRouter
Content-Length: 8786
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header> <!-- ... --> 
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://actualDestination</a:To>
</s:Header> <!-- ... body, /envelope, etc --->
```

I'm currently able to set other custom headers that the routing service requires by using [Custom Behaviors](http://Handling%20custom%20SOAP%20headers%20via%20WCF%20Behaviors) without a problem:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    request = buffer.CreateMessage();
    request.Headers.To = new Uri("http://actualDestination");
    request.Headers.Add(new CustomHeader());
    return null;
}
```

The above code works fine to add my CustomHeader to the message, but fails to modify the outgoing WS-Addressing `To` field - it always gets set back to the same URI as the HTTP POST  value. In fact, I used .NET Reflector to debug when this field gets set- and sure enough, it is getting overwritten ([screenshot of the stack trace and breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iqjh.png)).

Is there some other way for me to change the `To` SOAP header that I'm not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own with a [hint from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/1a5f41a8-9c3d-4b4f-9c24-3d659fdb045d). Programatically, I can set the `Via` on the `ClientRuntime` inside the [custom behavior](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx). This allows the POST to differ from the actual endpoint address that gets set automatically due to my usage of WSHttpBinding.

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior
    (ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
{
    CustomMessageInspector inspector = new CustomMessageInspector();
    clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
    clientRuntime.Via = new Uri("http://gatewayRouter/routingService");
}
```